# Hive XML Serde - NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION

Tags: xml, exception, hadoop, hive

I am new to Hadoop/Hive. I want to create a Hive script with XML input. So, I have [this](https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe) link for getting the serde. There is a jar packaged in that and I used it for the Hive script.

This is the way I am executing the Hive statements..

```
[biadmin@bng xml]$ hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/biadmin/hive/lib/hive-common-0.13.1.jar!/hive-log4j.properties

hive> add jar /home/biadmin/scripts/hivexmlserde-1.0.0.0.jar;                               
Added /home/biadmin/scripts/hivexmlserde-1.0.0.0.jar to class path
Added resource: /home/biadmin/scripts/hivexmlserde-1.0.0.0.jar

hive> create external table if not exists xmltest (id varchar(50), name varchar(50), type varchar(50), dependency varchar(50), values varchar(50))
    > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    > "column.xpath.id"="/recs/rec/id/text()",
    > "column.xpath.name"="/recs/rec/name/text()",
    > "column.xpath.type"="/recs/rec/type/text()",
    > "column.xpath.dependency"="/recs/rec/dependency/text()",
    > "column.xpath.values"="/recs/rec/values/text()"
    > )
    > STORED AS
    > INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
    > OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    > TBLPROPERTIES (
    > "xmlinput.start"="<Par as",
    > "xmlinput.end"="</Par>"
    > );
OK
Time taken: 0.126 seconds

hive> load data local inpath '/home/biadmin/scripts/xml/playcontent.xml' into table xmltest;
Copying data from file:/home/biadmin/scripts/xml/playcontent.xml
Copying file: file:/home/biadmin/scripts/xml/playcontent.xml
Loading data to table default.xmltest
Table default.xmltest stats: [numFiles=3, numRows=0, totalSize=1842, rawDataSize=0]
OK
Time taken: 0.807 seconds

hive> select * from xmltest;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.NullPointerException
Time taken: 0.305 seconds

hive>
```

The XML I am trying to use is as follows...

```
<Par as="val">
    <recs>
        <rec>
            <id>servicedescription</id>
            <name>Description</name>
            <type>textbox</type>
            <dependency>1</dependency>
            <values>1</values>
        </rec>
        <rec>
            <id>contentlist</id>
            <name>Content File/s</name>
            <type>selectmul</type>
            <dependency>1</dependency>
            <values>1</values>
        </rec>
        <rec>
            <id>seek</id>
            <name>Seek</name>
            <type>checkbox</type>
            <dependency>1</dependency>
            <values>1</values>
        </rec>
    </recs>
</Par>
```

Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a typo in the table definition missing a ); before the select and I think that the location needs to before the table properties

Comment: Oh... Missing ")" was a copy paste mistake. Sorry. I tried moving the "location" up. But, it ended up giving an exception... " FAILED: ParseException line 6:0 missing EOF at 'WITH' near ''/home/biadmin/scripts/xml'' "

Comment: In addition to it, table xmltest is created when I go into hive shell. But querying it gives me an exception... "FAILED: RuntimeException MetaException(message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe not found)" .. I have added the jar in hive. Why is this exception coming ?? Any idea

Comment: @cbf1304 .. I resolved that issue. I forgot to add "SERDE" keyword in "ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe' " ... That resolved the issue. Please help me out in the modified question if possible. Will be much appreciated.

Comment: Good spot, is there anything useful in the job log? http://<NN>:50030/jobtracker.jsp

Comment: Nothing useful. Just went through it. No warnings. No Error messages.

Comment: So, you have fixed the serde issue. So, what's the new error?

Comment: select * from table_name results in "Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.NullPointerException" ... Please check code section for more info. Thanks. :)

Comment: which version of hive are you running? will see if i can get it working on my commute home.

Comment: hive version is 0.13.1 ...

Comment: Any help i can get ??

Answer (score 0):

Try out these as values for `column.xpath.<your attribute-name>` property in your CREATE statement.

```
"column.xpath.id"="Par/recs/rec/id/text()",
"column.xpath.name"="Par/recs/rec/name/text()",
"column.xpath.type"="Par/recs/rec/type/text()",
"column.xpath.dependency"="Par/recs/rec/dependency/text()", 
"column.xpath.values"="Par/recs/rec/values/text()"
```

I believe this modification will work for you.